# How to make overlapping windows of weeks based on the nearest available dates in both sides?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

Sorry guys for the title but it is really what I'm trying to do.

Here is a table to explain that more. The bold lines makes the years and the the thin ones makes the weeks.

[image]

For the expected output. It really doesn't matter its format. All I need is that if I ask for the dates of a pair `YEAR/WEEK`, I get the corresponding window of dates.

For example, if I do `some_window_function(2022, 5)` I should have the result below (it correspond to the **RED WINDOW**)

```
                                  DATE
YEAR WEEK                             
2020 30          Friday, July 24, 2020
2022 5     Wednesday, February 2, 2022
     5      Thursday, February 3, 2022
     5        Friday, February 4, 2022
     7      Tuesday, February 15, 2022
```

And for example, if I do `some_window_function(2022, 7)` I should have the result below (it correspond to the **BLUE WINDOW**)

```
                                   DATE
YEAR WEEK                              
2022 5         Friday, February 4, 2022
2022 7       Tuesday, February 15, 2022
     7     Wednesday, February 16, 2022
     7      Thursday, February 17, 2022
2023 44       Tuesday, October 31, 2023
```

The dataframe used is this :

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'YEAR': [2020, 2020, 2020, 2020, 2020, 2020, 2020, 2022, 2022, 2022, 2022, 2022, 2022, 2023, 2023, 2023, 2023, 2023, 2023, 2023, 2023, 2023, 2023, 2023], 'WEEK': [29, 29, 29, 30, 30, 30, 30, 5, 5, 5, 7, 7, 7, 44, 44, 44, 44, 45, 45, 45, 46, 46, 46, 46], 'DATE': ['Monday, July 13, 2020', 'Thursday, July 16, 2020', 'Friday, July 17, 2020', 'Monday, July 20, 2020', 'Tuesday, July 21, 2020', 'Thursday, July 23, 2020', 'Friday, July 24, 2020', 'Wednesday, February 2, 2022', 'Thursday, February 3, 2022', 'Friday, February 4, 2022', 'Tuesday, February 15, 2022', 'Wednesday, February 16, 2022', 'Thursday, February 17, 2022', 'Tuesday, October 31, 2023', 'Wednesday, November 02, 2023', 'Friday, November 03, 2023', 'Sunday, November 05, 2023', 'Monday, November 06, 2023', 'Tuesday, November 07, 2023', 'Wednesday, November 08, 2023', 'Monday, November 13, 2023', 'Tuesday, November 14, 2023', 'Wednesday, November 15, 2023', 'Thursday, November 16, 2023']})
```

I made the code below but it gives a similar dataframe to my input :

```
def make_windows(group):
    if group.name == df.loc[df['YEAR'] == group.name, 'WEEK'].min():
        group.at[group.index[-1]+1, 'DATE'] = df.at[group.index[-1]+1, 'DATE']
        return group.ffill()

    elif group.name < df.loc[df['YEAR']== group.name, 'WEEK'].max():
        group.at[group.index[-1]+1, 'DATE'] = df.at[group.index[-1]+1, 'DATE']
        return group.iloc[1:].ffill()
    else:
        return group.iloc[1:].ffill()

results = df.groupby('YEAR').apply(make_windows)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like you could use a simple mask for the YEAR/WEEK and expand it one row above/below (assuming sorted dates):

```
df = df.sort_values(by=['YEAR', 'WEEK'])

def some_window_function(year, week):
    mask = df['YEAR'].eq(year) & df['WEEK'].eq(week)
    return df[mask|mask.shift()|mask.shift(-1)]

some_window_function(2022, 5)
```

Output:

```
    YEAR  WEEK                         DATE
6   2020    30        Friday, July 24, 2020
7   2022     5  Wednesday, February 2, 2022
8   2022     5   Thursday, February 3, 2022
9   2022     5     Friday, February 4, 2022
10  2022     7   Tuesday, February 15, 2022
```

Comment: You're a wonderful person. You can't imagine the relief I feel now after weeks of struggling. Have a nice day.

Answer (score 1):

Ok, this is how you can achieve this:

```py
import pandas as pd

# Creating the DataFrame as provided
df = pd.DataFrame({
    'YEAR': [2020, 2020, 2020, 2020, 2020, 2020, 2020, 2022, 2022, 2022, 2022, 2022, 2022, 2023, 2023, 2023, 2023, 2023, 2023, 2023, 2023, 2023, 2023, 2023],
    'WEEK': [29, 29, 29, 30, 30, 30, 30, 5, 5, 5, 7, 7, 7, 44, 44, 44, 44, 45, 45, 45, 46, 46, 46, 46],
    'DATE': ['Monday, July 13, 2020', 'Thursday, July 16, 2020', 'Friday, July 17, 2020', 'Monday, July 20, 2020', 
             'Tuesday, July 21, 2020', 'Thursday, July 23, 2020', 'Friday, July 24, 2020', 'Wednesday, February 2, 2022', 
             'Thursday, February 3, 2022', 'Friday, February 4, 2022', 'Tuesday, February 15, 2022', 
             'Wednesday, February 16, 2022', 'Thursday, February 17, 2022', 'Tuesday, October 31, 2023', 
             'Wednesday, November 02, 2023', 'Friday, November 03, 2023', 'Sunday, November 05, 2023', 
             'Monday, November 06, 2023', 'Tuesday, November 07, 2023', 'Wednesday, November 08, 2023', 
             'Monday, November 13, 2023', 'Tuesday, November 14, 2023', 'Wednesday, November 15, 2023', 
             'Thursday, November 16, 2023']
})
def get_week_data(df, year, week):
    # Creating a continuous year-week identifier (e.g., "2020-30", "2022-5") as a temporary series
    year_week_series = df['YEAR'].astype(str) + '-' + df['WEEK'].astype(str)

    # Finding the unique and sorted year-week combinations
    unique_year_weeks = sorted(year_week_series.unique())

    # Defining the target year-week combination
    target_year_week = f"{year}-{week}"

    # Check if the target year-week combination exists in the data
    if target_year_week not in unique_year_weeks:
        return pd.DataFrame()  # Return empty DataFrame if not found

    # Finding the index of the specified year-week
    year_week_index = unique_year_weeks.index(target_year_week)

    # Determining the previous and next year-week based on index
    previous_year_week = unique_year_weeks[year_week_index - 1] if year_week_index > 0 else None
    next_year_week = unique_year_weeks[year_week_index + 1] if year_week_index < len(unique_year_weeks) - 1 else None

    # Filtering rows for the specified week, previous week, and next week
    specified_week_data = df[year_week_series == target_year_week]
    previous_week_data = df[year_week_series == previous_year_week].iloc[-1:] if previous_year_week is not None else pd.DataFrame()
    next_week_data = df[year_week_series == next_year_week].iloc[:1] if next_year_week is not None else pd.DataFrame()

    # Combining the data
    combined_data = pd.concat([previous_week_data, specified_week_data, next_week_data])

    return combined_data

# Example usage for the year 2022 and week 5
result = get_week_data(df.copy(), 2022, 5)
result
```

It does return for 2022, 7:

```
YEAR  WEEK                         DATE
6   2020    30        Friday, July 24, 2020
7   2022     5  Wednesday, February 2, 2022
8   2022     5   Thursday, February 3, 2022
9   2022     5     Friday, February 4, 2022
10  2022     7   Tuesday, February 15, 2022
```

and for 2022, 5:

```
    YEAR  WEEK                         DATE
6   2020    30        Friday, July 24, 2020 
7   2022     5  Wednesday, February 2, 2022   
8   2022     5   Thursday, February 3, 2022
9   2022     5     Friday, February 4, 2022 
10  2022     7   Tuesday, February 15, 2022
```